# sometimes DataGrid claims focus when loading

Tags: gwt, datagrid, focus

I've a text box to enter a search string.

After typing a character, after 200 ms, a call to reload the DataGrid is done. The DataGrid has several columns with hyperlinks in the first column.
Sometimes when typing characters in the search text box, the DataGrid claims the focus and the first hyperlink is focused.

Is this some known bug or is there any way to debug/detect which part of the code is actually claiming the focus on the DataGrid?
Is it possible to install a hook somewhere to see the actual stacktrace when the focus event appears?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you do with your DataGrid in this reload call? Do you refresh the data provider or redraw the DataGrid?